# Auto generated styles.css wrong path to less file

Tags: css, less, magento2

I recently ran a composer script that moved the mageplaza core files into
 the vendor directory.

Now the admin section is giving me this error:

```
FileError: 'http://localhost:8000/static/version1494961173/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Mageplaza_Core/css/source/_module.less' wasn't found (404)
in styles.css on line 16, column 1:

15
16@import '../Mageplaza_Core/css/source/_module.less';
17@import '../Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation/css/source/_module.less';
```

I ran this command with no luck:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

It is still looking at the old location of the module.less file inside the app directory. How do I fix this?